# How to get the number of elements in std::array<T, N> without having to create its instance?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, sizeof

There is `std::array<T, N>::size()`, but it's non-static, so it requires an instance of `std::array`. Is there a way to get the value it returns (which is the `N` of `std::array<T, N>`) without having to construct an instance of the array? For a normal array, I could have used `sizeof`, but I see no guarantee that `sizeof(std::array<T, N>) == N * sizeof(T)` be true.

Comment: If you have `N`, why do you need to ask `array` to reproduce it for you?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Because `sizeof(std::array<T, N>) == N * sizeof(T)` doesn't have to be true.

Comment: Because the array may be typedefed elsewhere or be passed as an argument to a template.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The question is about number of elements, not size in bytes; `sizeof` isn't really relevant. Apparently there is a simple solution though, `std::tuple_size` is new to me.

Comment: Yes I'm confused by the disparity between the title and the last sentence of the question. Do you want to know the number of elements or the number of bytes?

Comment: The number of elements. Using `sizeof` divided by an element size is a standard C trick to get that value.

Comment: If you want to know the number of elements, just use `N`.

Comment: @dragonroot What is the point of all this, though? If you already have `N` to begin with, there is no need to go through all this to get `N` indirectly, or to validate that `N==N`. What is the actual *use case* that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's [`std::tuple_size<std::array>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size).

```c++
static_assert(std::tuple_size<std::array<int, 5>>::value == 5);
```

Comment: Wouldn't plain [std::size()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) do?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Actually no, `std::size()` requires an instance of the array.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `tuple_size` like this though, if you already know the array size up front to pass it into the template.  Maybe this would be a more meaningful example? `using ArrayType = std::array<int, 5>; ... static_assert(std::tuple_size<ArrayType>::value == 5);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I guess the O/P is thinking the array decl has been passed in as a template argument to a template function?  Even then the only purpose I can see is to assign it as the returned object, which still requires an instance to be created.